# Update Fields on Object B, 5 days after the expiration on Object A

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, lightning-flow-builder, flow-builder, updaterecord

I am pretty new with Flows builder.

I am trying to create a flow that updates a picklist field and a checkbox field on **Object B's record** after 5 days of an expiration date on **Object A's**.

**Object A is a parent of Object B**

**Example:**
The expiration date on a Deal object is 4/20/2023 in 5 Day I want a picklist to be set to "Off Market" and a verification checkbox to be unchecked on the Listing object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a record-triggered flow with scheduled paths

- Run Flow on Object A
- Entry condition Expiration Date not equal NULL
- Immediate Path = do nothing
- Scheduled Path +5 days from Expiration Date

Flow body - `Get Records` for Object B(s) that are children of Object A (basically `ObjectA__c = $Record.Id`)

- Loop through results and set the picklist field on the retrieved Object B's
- Update Records

Comment: Thank you this helps. I seem to get stuck on the last 3 elements.

Flow body - Get Records for Object B(s) that are children of Object A (basically ObjectA__c = $Record.Id) 

Loop through results and set the picklist field on the retrieved Object B's
Update Records

I can't figure out of to get the record I need. The loop ends everytime I try and it says fail to find record

Comment: you'll need to use [edit] and amend your post showing the Flow you have constructed.